# How do I cast address of a class method to (void *)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, architecture, x86

```
class Foo{
public:
    void Bar();
}
```

It doesn't have to be safe and I don't care about `this` pointer. I just need to get the address of Bar function located in the memory on **x86**

`void *address = (void *)&(Foo::Bar)` does not work.

`void *address = (void *)(&Foo::Bar)` does not work.

`void *address = (void *)Foo::Bar` does not work.

**EDIT:** Let me clarify this. Even it's theoretically illegal to cast a function pointer to an object because a functions may well be located in another memory space, in reality, they are the same. As I have mentioned earlier, it neither has to be safe, nor be legal. I've added x86 tag to the question. It only has to work on gcc, and MSVC on x86 architecture.

Comment: Why do you want to take it in a `void*`? Can you not use function pointer?

Comment: I need the integral value and it needs to be generic as possible.

Comment: Please test your code before posting your code!! Thanks

Comment: Suppose `Bar()` is `virtual`. Consider how you would implement a member pointer. See, on sane platofrms that will never fit into a `void*`.

Comment: that's why I didn't declare it as `virtual`.

Comment: Related: [How do I print the address of a method pointer in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5367152/140719).

Comment: @JosephH: Yes, but a member function type _could_ point to a virtual function, so the underlying data structure needs to take this into account, even if you happen to assign a non-virtual function to it.

Comment: I'm limiting my comment to programs compiled by MSVC, gcc, g++ on x86. That's why I've added bunch of tags related to those specific architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use x86 assembly:

On MSVC:

```
__asm{
    mov eax, (Foo::Bar);
    mov address, eax;
}
```

On g++:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("mov %1, %0":"=r"(address):"r"(&Foo::Bar));
```

Comment: I'd still like to know why you're doing this.

Answer (score 9):

You don't and you can't. Pointers-to-member-function **are not pointers** (to objects, i.e they're not `T*` for any type `T`). They don't necessarily, and not even practically, fit into a `void*`.

The only thing you know about `void*` is that it is big enough to hold any object pointer. That's it. It's not even related to ordinary free function pointers. In a crunch, you can define a free-function analogue of a void pointer as `typedef void(*voidf)();`, but that's only for free functions. For pointers-to-member function there is no general such thing, as the precise implementation of the PTMF depends on the nature of the class (simple, polymorphic, virtually derived, ...).

Comment: Of course they are pointers, they just point to a different type.

Comment: @myrkos: Do an experiment Check the size of an pointer and size of an pointer to member function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it doesn't even practically fit into a `void *`. Member function is simply an **address** in memory that the program calls. and since `void *` also holds an **address**, i don't see why it wouldn't fit into a pointer.

Comment: @myrkos: They're not "pointers-to-object", which is what "pointer" usually means. I can make that more explicit, though.

Comment: @myrkos: They're not pointers. They could be objects of some structs defined by the compiler. Those objects are not a pointers. So `sizeof(such_object)`  may be different from `sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: Reference: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.10

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you CAN with pure C++ but in many cases just for fun or for checking how good you are with pointers) However it could be used to add more dynamic behavior to a program.

```
struct A {
    void f1() {
        printf("f1:\n");
    }

    void f2() {
        printf("f2:\n");
    }
};

A a;

char f[sizeof(&A::f1)];
{
    void (A::*i)(void) = &A::f1;
    memcpy(f, &i, sizeof(f));
    (a.*i)();
}
(a.*(*(void (A::**)(void)) &f))();

{
    void (A::*i)(void) = &A::f2;
    memcpy(f, &i, sizeof(f));
    (a.*i)();
}
(a.*(*(void (A::**)(void)) &f))();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a function pointer to a void pointer.  Check the [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.10) for more details

Comment: (-1) There is a difference between global function pointers and class function pointers ("methods"), they work different.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast the address of an object function ("method") as a global "plain pointer".

In order to be called, a method requires the reference of the object.

if you have this:

```
class MyClass
{
  void Hello(char* AName) { ... }
}

void main()
{
  MyClass MyObject = new MyClass();
  MyObject->Hello("World");
  delete MyObject;
}
```

The program is, internally, doing something like this:

```
void main()
{
  MyClass MyObject = new MyClass();
  Hello(MyObject, "World");
  delete MyObject;
}
```

Why do you want to do that ?

You want the address of a method, as **a solution for a problem**.

What is your programming problem ?
Maybe there is another way to solve it .

Comment: Did you mean `delete MyObject;`, or is this some funky unusual syntax?

Comment: @RobH Fixed. Its kind of difficult to remember each syntax, especially if daily job has to do with: C#, PHP, C++, at the same time :-s